Fluent Validation execute rule depending on multiple other rules
Let's say we have a few validators:
RuleFor(request => request.User)
    .NotEmpty()
    .Must(Exist);

RuleFor(request => request.Room)
    .NotEmpty()
    .Must(Exist);

RuleFor(request => request.Room)
    .Must(UserMustHavePermissionForThisRoom);

How can I execute the third rule only if the two other rules pass without using cascading behavior, if possible. I have read somewhere that I can basically validate the request and then just put everything in either ChildRules or DependentRules like so:
RuleFor(request => request)
    .ChildRules((inlineValidator) => {
        inlineValidator.RuleFor(request => request.UserId)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Must(Exist);
        inlineValidator.RuleFor(request => request.Room)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Must(Exist);
    })
    .DependenRules(() => {
        RuleFor(request => request.Room)
            .Must(UserMustHavePermissionForThisRoom);
    });

This will make the validator work like I need it to. But this also messes up some placeholders in the validation messages (like PropertyName), I think it is because I basically start with validating the request itself, and I don't really want to deal with having to manage every single property manually (my validator is quite big with some complex validations).
Is there are better way of handling conditional validations like this?

I usually guard conditional rules with a When():
RuleFor(request => request.Room)
    .Must(UserMustHavePermissionForThisRoom)
    .When(UserAndRoomExist);

This requires a bit of duplicate-looking logic in the UserAndRoomExist method, but if this logic is simple I wouldn't worry too much about the duplication. You can always spin that logic off into private methods which are called from the two other Exist methods and the UserAndRoomExist method. Depending on the arguments, you might be able to call the other Exist methods in UserAndRoomExist.
As an alternative, consider returning true in the UserMustHavePermissionForThisRoom if either the room or user does not exist. There would be an implicit dependency on the other Exist methods working properly. Potentially a user that does not exist could book a room that does not exist if there was a defect in the other validators, but it would be fairly easy to write unit tests covering those test cases.
